# Load Runner Decompression Error

Tags: loadrunner

Action.c(107): Warning -26601: Decompression function (wgzMemDecompressBuffer) failed, return code=-3 (Z_DATA_ERROR), inSize=740, inUse=0, outUse=0     [MsgId: MWAR-26601]

How to handle the above Error? 
When do i get this error?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your load generator is overloaded.   Take care to monitor the health of your load gens, keep logging to an absolute minimum and the number of users deliberately underloaded on the host to prevent being resource bound on CPU, DISK, Memory or Network.....which in turn would slow your virtual users, cause errors similar to what you are experiencing, and generally attack the integrity of the test.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer for the same issue as you have:

```
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/LR-LoadRunner/epeSF7uSf-Q
```

**Copy from the post**

---BEGIN COPY---

That particular error is pretty common. Apparently certain devices
implement *http deflate compression slightly differently from what LR
expects*, resulting in intermittent errors on some transactions, usualy
particular resource downloads.

While this forum discussion
(http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=550003) seems to say
resource starvation at the load generator side may be the cause, I
have never observed it in conditions where resource utilisation on the
generator was an issue.

There are several solutions to this:

1) Add the following line to the top of your script:
web_add_auto_headder("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

This disables the 'deflate' compression method by defaulting to the gzip method.

2) Change the compression method in your runtime settings: Preferences

> Options > Accept server side compression. (May need some fiddling
>   before it works, I never seem to remember which options should be on
>   and which shouldn't be..)

3) Find the offending resource - usually a flash object or picture and
take it out of the offending transaction - either by removing it from
the EXTRARES section, or by means of web_add_filter(). Then put that
in it's own web_url() call, with the proper 'RecContentType' header
attached - eg. "RecContentType=application/x-shockwave-flash".

Why the last option seems to work for some applications beats me.
Frankly, it looks like a bug in Loadrunner - one that is a) very old
(these errors have been around since LR 8, at the least) and b) only
occurs in very specific circumstances that probably have never seen in
any HP lab.

Regards,
Floris
---END OF COPY---

Comment: From this post what worked for me was web_add_auto_header("Accept-Encoding", "deflate")

Answer (score 0):

Disable antivirus. That always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Increase Network buffer size in Preferences -> Options tab. It helped me to avoid Decompression error.